# how to protect my Web API Basic Authentication credentials

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api

I've just started implementing Authentication in my Web API.
I want to start with Basic Authentication

I learned that i've to pass Username and Password in every request.
So, lets say i'm doing some Admin task and making API call for same like this:

```
 $.ajax({
          url: host + "homework/delete/" + $(this).data("id"),
          type: 'DELETE',
          headers:
                    {
                        Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password)
                    },
          success: function (d) {
                   $tr.remove();
          },
          error: function () {
                 alert("Error please try again");
          }
  });
```

So, although my username/password is in variable, but their value must be at page(source). whosoever access that page, can see those credentials.
That means, whosoever get to know the url of that page, can see the credentials.

If i put a login page, how should i check on admin page that this user is authenticated. Should i use Cookies? to set something if user is coming through login page?

Comment: you can encrypt your username and password by CryptoJS

Comment: but that would be visible too, my point is how to protect that page getting accessed from unauthenticated users

Answer (score 0):

To enhance security, I think there should be another approach. At first you need to authenticate to you service using username and password, and receive authentication token with limited lifetime, then you should use this token to access your services.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to choose another approach:

1. create a server side application with UI (PHP, Java, ...)
2. this application has a session management
3. the credentials are stored in the configuration of the server side app
4. the requests to the service which is secured by Basic Authentication are performed by the server app. The responses are delivered to the client

You can't hide the credentials if you are creating a client side JavaScript application. Another issue with your approach maybe this: does the secured service support CORS (cross origin resource sharing) ?

Comment: Most of the applications hese days are made using html/js plus Web APIs. I just want to know is there any way to prevent unauthenticated access to admin page. I believe i should call some auth api on page load